# Gui mode emacs from Cygwin64 command line?

Tags: emacs, command-line, cygwin

When I launch Emacs from the Cygwin (64-bit) command line, it always goes into text mode, as if I had launched it *emacs -nw*. How can I get it to launch in a separate window?

Comment: My environment is Emacs version is 24.5.1; 64-bit Cygwin running under Windows 7

Comment: Have you [installed the `xorg` Cygwin package](http://x.cygwin.com/)?

Comment: IIRC you'll need xorg installed; you'll need to ensure you've *started* X (most likely you'll want to use the option that produces Windows-native windows, rather than a single large X container window), and then you'll want to ensure that Emacs is aware of the display (perhaps by running it from an xterm).

Comment: Phils, I have xorg installed.  I'm running startxwin without any command-line parameters, and emacs is launching into the mintty window. Which option tells it to start Windows-native windows?  I'm not seeing one that appears to do anything of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you install the emacs-w32 package. It doesn't need X and has much better font rendering (Emacs with Consolas, anyone?). With it installed just running "emacs-w32" opens a new GUI frame.